# Copying data from a table when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am learning coding and trying to make a simple food ordering website.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline-warning" CommandName="SepetEkle" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' ID="btnYemekSepetEkle" Text="Sepete Ekle">
```

when I click this button, I want my selected food to copy from "Yemekler" to "Sepet"

```
if(e.CommandName == "SepetEkle")
{
     using (SiparisDaBa())
     {
        Guid Id = Guid.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        var sepet = db.Sepet.FirstOrDefeault(t => t.SepetID == Id);
        db.Sepet.Add(sepet);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

I know the problem, I should look at the primary key of the food from "Yemekler" table and then I should copy it to "Sepet" table so when I click the order button, it wont take all of the food in the list. but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: you are using `FirstOrDefault()` so only first record is pulled back from db, you need to use `Where()` if you need to process all matching rows

Comment: and what's the problem? are you getting an error?

Comment: @derloopkat https://prnt.sc/j8zubq this is the problem. I am not using viewtables because I didnt understand them properly. my main problem is when I click http://prntscr.com/j8zvp9 on the yellow button, I want to copy primary key of that thing I click on and paste it to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new instance of Sepet in order to insert it into Sepet table. I haven't tried your code, but I believe you need something like this.

```
Guid Id = Guid.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
var yemekler = db.Yemekler.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == Id);
if(yemekler != null)
{
    //after id, include other fields separated by comma
    var sepet = new Sepet() { ID = yemekler.ID };
    db.Sepet.Add(sepet);
    db.SaveChanges();
};
```

When initialising new instance `new Sepet()` you can include other relevant fields from yemekler that you want to be in sepet, apart from ID.